# Factoring Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have to complete a factoring packet for AP Calculus, and I'm having trouble with three of the questions...

Find the missing factor:

1.
        $2\sqrt{x} + 6x^\frac 32 = 2\sqrt{x}$(**_____________**)

I was thinking that the missing factor would be 1+3x? I'm not sure.

2.
        $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ (**__________**)

3.
        $(2x+1)^\frac 32\left(x^\frac 12\right)+(2x +1)^\frac 52(x^\frac {-1}{2})=(2x+1)^\frac 32(x^\frac {-1}{2})$(**______________**)

Comment: For (1) you are right. Can check by multiplying: $2\sqrt{x}(1+3x)$ gives the right thing.  For (2) bring the right-hand side to a common denominator.

Comment: what does \frac -12 mean (in problem 3)? It renders as $\frac -12$

Comment: someone please clean this up....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Let's see if the missing factor is $1+3x$:

$$2\sqrt{x}+6x^{\frac{3}{2}}=2\sqrt{x}(1+3x)=2 \sqrt{x}+6x \sqrt{x}=2 \sqrt{x}+6x^{1+\frac{1}{2}}=2 \sqrt{x}+6x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

So, it is correct!

1. At the first term, you could multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x^2+1}$:

   $$\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \left ( \left (\sqrt{x^2+1} \right )^2-x^2\right )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \left ( x^2+1-x^2\right )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$

3.
        $$(2x+1)^\frac 32\left(x^\frac 12\right)+(2x +1)^\frac{5}{2}(x^\frac{-1}{2})$$

Use that $(2x +1)^\frac{5}{2}=(2x +1)^\frac{3}{2}(2x +1)^\frac{2}{2}=(2x +1)^\frac{3}{2}(2x +1)$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}x$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

HINTS: I assume the question is to solve the equations.

1. You have $2\sqrt{x}+6x\sqrt{x}=2\sqrt{x}$.  Subtract $2\sqrt{x}$ and then factor out $\sqrt{x}$
2. $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$  Multiply by  $\sqrt{x^2+1}$
3. $(2x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \left( x^\frac{1}{2}\right)+(2x +1)^\frac{5}{2}(x^\frac{-1}{2})=(2x+1)^\frac{3}{2}(x^\frac{-1}{2})$ Subtact $(2x +1)^\frac{5}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$ and then factor out $(2x +1)^\frac{5}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$.

Comment: I don't know why the third item changed the 3 to a 1, but I can't seem to get it to stay a 3.

Comment: I fixed it by inserting a space between "$2.$" and "$\sqrt{x^2+1}$".

Comment: The question does not ask for the solution of an equation, it asks for "the missing factor."

Comment: @ TonyK Thanks, that was driving me nuts.